# Is the language given by a context-free grammar always context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Consider the language generated by the following grammar:

$S \to aSBb \mid \epsilon$

$B \to aB \mid bB \mid \epsilon$

Is the above language context-free?

---

The above language looks like $\{ w \in (a+b)^* : a^n w_1b w_2b ... w_nb \}$.

I tried using the pumping lemma to show that this language is not context-free, but I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: A language $L$ is context-free iff there exists a context-free grammar $G$ such that $L = L(G)$. (Some people take this as the *definition* of context-free languages.)

Comment: Damn, I didn't see that the grammar itself is CFG and was trying to construct a PDA. But the language is not DCFL right ?

Comment: That's a different question.